# I am trying to get a string of sequence numbers but getting an error saying variable not defined

Tags: python, indentation

I am getting a error saying that the variable is not defined.  Is it because it is considered a local variable and therefor cannot be used. Any insight appreciated. Thanks

This is the error..
***addedNum = pNum + fNum + sNum
NameError: name 'pNum' is not defined***

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3rtq.png)

```
def Print():
    print('Police ' + str(pNum) + 'Fire ' + str(fNum) + 'Sanitation ' + str(sNum)) 



def checkPrint():
    addedNum = pNum + fNum + sNum
    if pNum%2 == 0:
        if  addedNum == 12:
            print()
    
def printDept():
    pNum = 0
    fNum = 0
    sNum = 0
    while pNum < 8:
        checkPrint()
        pNum = pNum + 1
        while fNum < 8:
            checkPrint()
            fNum = fNum + 1
            while sNum < 8:
                checkPrint()
                sNum = sNum + 1


printDept()
```

Comment: title says "indent error" but your message says "variable is not defined". So which one is it?

Comment: Variables have a function scope. `pNum` is declared in `printDept()` function, but you are trying to use it in `checkPrint()`, where it is not declared. That's why you're getting the error. Optimally you have to pass it inside the function as a parameter.

Comment: When defining a function you must add the variables you want to process in the function definition. `def checkPrint(pNum, fNum, sNum):`

Answer (score 0):

When you are running `checkPrint()` from within the `printDept()` function, the variables defined within `printDept()` (`pNum`, `fNum` and `sNum`) are not passed on so are not found in the namespace local to `checkPrint()`.

To run `checkPrint()` with the variables `pNum`, `fNum` and `sNum`, you need to change the `changePrint()` function to require three arguments, and then pass those arguments in during the running of `printDept()`:

```py
def checkPrint(pNum, fNum, sNum):
    addedNum = pNum + fNum + sNum
    if pNum%2 == 0:
        if  addedNum == 12:
            print()
    
def printDept():
    pNum = 0
    fNum = 0
    sNum = 0
    while pNum < 8:
        checkPrint(pNum, fNum, sNum)
        pNum = pNum + 1
        while fNum < 8:
            checkPrint(pNum, fNum, sNum)
            fNum = fNum + 1
            while sNum < 8:
                checkPrint(pNum, fNum, sNum)
                sNum = sNum + 1

printDept()
```